# Redirect input from a file to a java JAR in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux

I have a *.jar file. Its *.java reads from console a undefined number of lines. It uses `SimpleCharStream entryF = new SimpleCharStream(System.in);` for reading from the console.

My question is, without modifying the original class, is there anyway of making this *.jar read from a file?
I am using **ubuntu** and I have tried using redirections like:
`java -jar test.jar < entry.txt` but it says *"Invalid or corrupt jarfile test.jar"*

Thanks.

Comment: I'd try `cat entry.txt | java -jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates you aren't building the jar file correctly.

Comment: Then try Andrew's suggestion.

Comment: I have to apologize, it was corrupted. I rebuilt it and Andrew's solution worked.